# How to get the value of an input within its class index and assign it to another input with the same index in its own collection?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

excuse my noobness but bear with me.
lets say we have an arbitrary amount of inputs in a container 1,and some of them share a class.

we also have another container 2 and it has some amount of inputs inside and some of them also share a class

what i want is to replicate the value of the input in container 1 which has an index in the class `.inputs1` to the corresponding input in container 2 which has the same index in the class `.inputs2`

i know how to get the index of the input (in its class) im currently typing on using `var index1 = $(this).closest("input").index(".inputs1");`

i just dont know what jquery selector should i use to transfer the values
where should i start ?

snippet to visualize my concept :

```js
$(document).on("input", "input", function() {
  var index1 = $(this).closest("input").index(".inputs1");
  var index2 = $(this).closest("input").index(".inputs2");


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1">
  <input placeholder="container 1" class="inputs1"><input placeholder="container 1"><input placeholder="container 1" class="inputs1"><input placeholder="container 1"><input placeholder="container 1" class="inputs1">
</div>
<div id="container2">
  <input placeholder="container 2" class="inputs2"><input placeholder="container 2"><input placeholder="container 2" class="inputs2"><input placeholder="container 2"><input placeholder="container 2" class="inputs2">
</div>
```

Comment: so first input in container 1 will have same value as in container 2s 1st input  and so on ?

Comment: no,the input with class .inputs1 and index #1 in this class in container 1,will send its value to input with class .inputs2 and index #1 in its class in container 2 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:eq` to get same class from other div and then add value there as well.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on("input", "input", function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("inputs1")) {
    var index1 = $(this).index(".inputs1");
    //get class with same index 
    $("#container2").find(".inputs2:eq(" + index1 + ")").val($(this).val())
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container1">
    <input placeholder="container 1" class="inputs1">
    <input placeholder="container 1" class="inputs1">
    <input placeholder="container 1" class="inputs1">
    <input placeholder="container 1">
    <input placeholder="container 1" class="inputs1">
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div id="container2">
    <input placeholder="container 2" class="inputs2">
    <input placeholder="container 2" class="inputs2">
    <input placeholder="container 2" class="inputs2">
    <input placeholder="container 2">
    <input placeholder="container 2" class="inputs2">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy values only from inputs marked by class `.inputs1` to the ones with corresponding index in `#container2`:

```js
$(document).on("input", function(event) {
  let $currentInput = $(event.target)
  if ($currentInput.hasClass('inputs1')) {
    let inputToUpdate = $('#container2 input')[$currentInput.index()]
    $(inputToUpdate).val(event.target.value)
  }
});
```

Comment: i want to copy them to the ones with corresponding index with class .inputs2 in container 2

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different and perhaps easier to read approach

```js
const $in_1 = $('.inputs1'),
      $in_2 = $('.inputs2');


$in_1.on("input", function() {
  const inIdx = $in_1.index(this);  
  $in_2.eq(inIdx).val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container1">
  <input placeholder="container 1" class="inputs1" />
  <input placeholder="container 1" class="inputs1" />
  <input placeholder="container 1" class="inputs1" />
  <input placeholder="container 1" class="inputs1" />
</div>
<div id="container2">
  <input placeholder="container 2" class="inputs2" />
  <input placeholder="container 2" class="inputs2" />
  <input placeholder="container 2" class="inputs2" />
  <input placeholder="container 2" class="inputs2" />
</div>
```